# What are the Characteristics of the Ring $\mathbf F_{p}[X]/g$ (mod $g$, $g$ is non-irreducible)?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

$f(x)$ is a primitive polynomial of degree $m$ over a field $\mathbf F_{p^m}$.  As such, $\mathbf F_{p^m}[x]/f(x)$ forms a ring, with addition and multiplication ($\mkern-4mu\bmod f(x)$), and furthermore is a field since $f(x)$ is irreducible.  Call it $F$

Now, replace $f(x)$ with $g(x)$, a non-primitive, non-irreducible polynomial of degree $m$ over $\mathbf F_{p^m}$ and where $g(0) = 1$. Call it $G$.  I am having trouble finding information on line or referred to about the characteristics of such a $g$ or the algebraic structure of $G$ (a ring?).  This is probably because I don't know the right terminology and keywords regarding these to search by.  Fields and Rings are new to me.

Some questions I have are (assume $m > 2$):

1. There are a finite number of elements in $G$ (because it is modulo $g$), but it doesn't form a field.  What is it called?  A "finite-ring"?

**EDIT** removed prior questions about cycle.

2. For any non-zero $\alpha \in F$, $\exists n > 0$ such that $\alpha^n = 1$.  This is not true for all $\alpha \in G$.  Can we easily determine the ones that **do** have such an $n$?
3. For any non-zero $\alpha \in F$, the powers of $\alpha$ form a closed group under multiplication.  Again, not true $G$.  In $G \exists \alpha$ whose powers never equal 1, so they cannot form a group (no multiplicative identity).  And when $g(x)$ is allowed to have factors with multiplicity > 1, $\exists \alpha  \in G$ such that $\alpha^k = 0, k \ge |\alpha|$.  However, there $\exists \alpha \in G$ that **do** have powers that form cyclic multiplicative groups. Can we easily determine which ones they are?

Can you point me to a link or a paper (or even just the proper terms to use for searching) that discusses more about this non-irreducible case?

Comment: Why should there be a finite number of elements in the ring?

Comment: What do you mean by a "cycle"?

Comment: @Bernard - the definition of this ring $g$ is that addition and multiplication are modulo $g$ (keeping many of the constraints that were given for $f(x)$)

Comment: But  $\mathbf F[x]/(g)$ isn't finite, unless $\mathbf F$ itself is:  $\mathbf R[x]/(x^2+1)\simeq \mathbf C$ is the simplest counter-example.

Comment: @Bernard - yes, I realized that and updated the question.

Comment: By the *Chinese remainder theorem*, it is an artinian $F$-algebra. If $g$ has no multiple irreducible factors (.i.e; if the algebra is a reduced ring), it is a product of field extensions of $F$. For the rest, I can't tell: I don't know what you call a ‘cycle’ here.

Comment: @Bernard has put his finger on the solution to the problem. When $g$ has an irreducible factor with multiplicity $>1$, there will be nilpotents in the resulting ring. Try $\mathbf F[x]/((x-a)^m)$, for instance, the simplest case of this.

Comment: @Bernard and Lubin - very helpful are the phrases "product of field extentions", "irreducible factor with multiplicity > 1", "no multiple irreducible factors", and "nilpotents".  First hits on Artinian F-Algegra lead to a couple of very difficult papers to digest (will search for something easier).  Chinese remainder theorem relates to "product of fields", I gather, so I am reviewing from that light.  It either or both of you form your responses as answers, I could probably close the question as answered, as I think I have enough to go on.